# Handle WTRX token withdraw and deposit from smartcontract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Hello I want to handle WTRX (WETH but on tronchain) token inside of my smart contract.
`deposit` seems to work, but the problem is on `withdraw` and `both` functions, those two fail with `REVERT opcode executed.` .

Before I call `withdraw` I have approved contract address from WTRX smart contract.

From my investigation I suppose that is from `msg.sender.transfer(sad)` inside the `wtrx.withdraw` function.

Does somebody know how to solve this problem and make this functions work? Thanks!

WTRX contract can be found here: https://tronscan.io/#/token20/TNUC9Qb1rRpS5CbWLmNMxXBjyFoydXjWFR/code

My contract code:

```
contract TestTransfer {
function deposit(address payable wtrxAddr) public payable{
    WTRX wtrx = WTRX(wtrxAddr);

    // TRX to WTRX Token
    wtrx.deposit.value(msg.value)();

    // Transfer TRX to caller
    wtrx.transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
}

function withdraw(address payable wtrxAddr, uint sad) public{
    WTRX wtrx = WTRX(wtrxAddr);

    // Transfer WTRX Token from owner to contract
    wtrx.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), sad);

    // WTRX Token to TRX
    wtrx.withdraw(sad);
    
    // Transfer TRX to caller
    msg.sender.transfer(sad);
}

function both(address payable wtrxAddr) public payable{
    WTRX wtrx = WTRX(wtrxAddr);
    // TRX to WTRX Token
    wtrx.deposit.value(msg.value)();
    
    // WTRX Token to TRX
    wtrx.withdraw(msg.value);

    // Transfer TRX to caller
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give some details about what your functions are trying to do?! I can't figure it out!

Comment: They get and burn WTRX from WTRX contract, WTRX is a WETH version for TRX on tronchain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare more failback function in your smart contract:

```
contract TestTransfer {
    receive() external payable {
    }
    
    // More your code here
    // ...
    // ...
}
```